# Azure Devops If condition not matching

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My countryCode parameter is "myathlon-be", but it seems like I always get null when evaluating parameters.countryCode inside the [conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion).

```
parameters:
- name: countryCode
  default: '$(countryCode)'
steps:
- script: |
      echo "this is the country code for the service ${{ parameters.countryCode }}" 
      
- ${{ if eq(parameters.countryCode, 'myathlon-be')  }}: 
  - script: 'echo i am belgium' 
- ${{ if ne('parameters.countryCode', 'myathlon-be')  }}: 
  - script: 'echo i am NL' 

output:

Generating script.
Script contents:
echo "this is the country code for the service myathlon-be"
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /var/build/Ubuntu0101/_work/_temp/7793af00-16c0-4fb7-a2db-ce48bfe9151a.sh
this is the country code for the service myathlon-be
Finishing: CmdLine

Generating script.
Script contents:
echo i am NL
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /var/build/Ubuntu0101/_work/_temp/bc8cdeba-ca32-48b6-923a-ae49cf8c3dee.sh
i am NL
Finishing: CmdLine
```

Thanks

Comment: Put it into one yaml to start with and og that fors not work share that mvp - so proppe Can see what is actually happening in your script 

Answer (score 0):

Given `countryCode` looks like it's a variable, it's likely that you are being caught out by the fact variables get expanded before tasks execute, but they won't be expanded when you do conditions because conditions need to present at compile time.

As a test, you can hard-code the parameter from the YAML calling this template and you should see it evaluates as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks james for the reply .

I fixed it differently by

defining the value the of parameter"countryCode" directly in the build.yml. Then choosing the value the of parameter"countryCode" in the main.yml.

Comment: That's basically what I was getting at, whatever value your parameter is being set as has to be guaranteed to be there at compile-time, calling the template from another YAML passing a fixed value is as good as hard-coding so will work.